# If I have a powerful modem is it wise to also use a router?

Tags: router, home-networking, modem

Trying to get the best performance and maintenance, is it wise to have an additional router attached to my modem that already has the features I use?

Currently I have all my devices connect to the router and the router wired to the modem thinking to let my router do all the routing and my modem do all the modulating.

Would I get better performance just direct to my modem for my devices getting rid of the router? Or splitting the connection to the two of them?

My current setup is:

- CenturyLink 20mbit/768kbit
  ActionTech Q1000 Modem - Built in single band Wifi.
- Netgear 3400v2 - Dual Band router

About 10 wireless devices, half can use 5gz.
Regular user of Bittorrent, Gaming, Video Streaming both up and down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the best setup is to use your modem only as a modem (in bridging mode) and your router as a router. The exception would be if you had a modem that had comparable features to your router.

The worst setup is double NAT where your modem is routing and your router is also routing. This is awful.

You can also use your modem as a router and use your router just as a switch and access point. To do this, turn off your router's DHCP server and don't use its WAN/Internet port.

Comment: Would this be the same as Transparent Bridging?

Comment: The modem would be doing transparent bridging.

Comment: great thanks I will try that, have to call CenturyLink as I don't know my PPPoE password